# Cannot Click Text

Tags: html, css

I am unable to click the text for the slides in a set of a layered `<div>`s.

If I try to select the text, I instead select the left/right arrows to switch slides.

However I'm just unable to make it so the text can be highlighted. The main reason is that I need to have a hyperlink on the last slide.

A simplified version of the offending HTML is as follows:

```html
<div class="tpslider">
  <div class="tpsliderreel">
    <div class="tpslidercell">Text content</div>
    <div class="tpslidercell">Text content</div>
    <div class="tpslidercell">Text content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tpslidercontrols">
    <div class="tpcontrolcell">Left arrow HTML</div>
    <div class="tpcontrolcell">Right arrow HTML</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS is as follows:

```css
.tpsliderreel {
    height: inherit;
    width: 1000%;
    position: absolute;
 transition: .75s ease-in-out;
}
.tpslidercontrols {
    height: inherit;
    width: 1000%;
    position: absolute;
}
.tpslidercell {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 8%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.tpcontrolcell {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 10%;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you guarantee the error will be reproducible under the URLs you posted in say, 10 years? If not, the question becomes worthless for subsequent readers as soon as the code changes there. SO is not mainly for you to be able to ask questions, it's main purpose is to serve as a reference where answers can be found via a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be simple Z-indexing issues. You have the left/right navigation buttons with a width of 1000% sitting on top of the text you wish to select. The easiest way to fix this is to increase the z-index of the text div.

For example, in your CSS for `.tpsliderreel`, add a line for `z-index: 99;` which should ensure that it's always on top of any other page elements.

Alternatively, you could decrease the `z-index` of `.tpslidercontrols` (your div with navigation arrows), but this approach is more likely to cause you to ask more questions or hack things up horribly in the future when things change.

Comment: Thank you for the support all. First time poster which some people seem to overlook. Lewellyn thanks so much that fixed it

Comment: connexo - if you put as much effort into helping as you do preaching you could run into a door hopefully